# Linux terminal single command resource usage

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, monitoring

I cant find way to monitor single Linux terminal command.

I want to monitor this command:

```
php index.php parse
```

The problem is this process works too short to get PID so I hope there is something like this:

```
singlecommandmonitor php index.php parse
```

Where `singlecommandmonitor` is software witch monitors RAM, CPU, etc. usage and `php index.php parse` is command I want to monitor. It should work similar to sudo, but instead of giving root permissions it should monitor resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple tool: [`time`](http://man.przez.net/time.1.html):

```
\time -v php index.php parse
```

Please note that the backslash (or `command time` or full path like `/usr/bin/time`) avoids executing of a shell built-in. For example bash has its own `time` built-in which does not not collect information about the process memory.

By default this tool shows the information in a shortened form. With the `-v` option it shows it with more understandable descriptions:

```
$ \time -v sleep 2
    Command being timed: "sleep 2"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:02.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2528
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 203
    Voluntary context switches: 2
    Involuntary context switches: 1
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is internal $! variable wicht contains pid. So this will do what I need:

```
php index.php parse & top -p $!
```